# why object.values({})'s type is unknown[]

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
var testObj = {};
const typeTest3 = Object.values(testObj);
```

Why is `typeTest3`'s type `unknown[]` while `Object.keys({})`'s type is `string[]` ?

Comment: It really *should* be `never[]` actually - `Object.values({})` is the empty array

Comment: @Bergi ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ `never` can also be correct but consider `function foo(obj: {}) { return Object.values(obj) }` and the call `foo({a: 1})` - the result is an array with a number in it. It's not something that cannot happen, there is just no type information

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, exactly that's what's happening - but the question would be whether the literal value `{}` should have type `{}` or rather `Record<string, never>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it produces an array that iterates over the values, which aren't guaranteed to have any specific type. `Object.values` has 1 generic type parameter though, so you can type the produced values yourself:

```js
Object.values<number>({a: 5, b: 3}).map(x => x + 3)
```

The type of `x` will be `number` instead of `unknown`.

(PS: `Object.keys` produces strings because in JavaScript all object keys are coerced into a string)

Comment: "*Object.keys produces strings because in JavaScript all object keys are coerced into a string*" not entirely correct - symbol are valid keys. However, `Object.keys()` does not return symbols. Also, supplying a generic in `Object.values<number>({a: 5, b: 3})` is not needed - TS infers the type as `number` correctly with `Object.values({a: 5, b: 3})`  [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgVwDawLwwPICMBWCwUAdAG4CGqySAFAN4UBcMArADQy4sDMAvgEoA3ACgA9GJhSYAPQD8QA)